# XPT2046 touch sensor problems

Tags: spi, touchscreen, micropython

I've got this [screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZGSPP1V) connected to a Raspberry Pi Pico running CircuitPython version 9.0.0. I'm trying to build an asynio application to read a sensor and display the value on the screen. I'm trying to use the XPT2046 touch sensor on the screen to navigate around the display. However, I'm getting what seem to be random values for the touch position. I created my touch code from adaptations of examples I've found on the internet. I have sample code I can share if anyone is interested, I didn't see a way to attach that to this messsage.

Any help, suggestions, pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Doug

Comment: what exactly is your question? ... it is difficult to accurately imagine your code

Comment: what is preventing you from copying the code and pasting it into your post?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mostly, I wasn't sure if copying fairly large sections of code directly into the post was a good idea.